# Any way to get the jester back?

Tags: overlord

I just finished the main storyline for Overlord on PC. At the ending of Overlord, the jester disappears.

> (because he's possessed by the 2nd Overlord)

Lore-wise, it doesn't make for the jester to remain at the tower, but I miss his banter. Is there any way to add him back through savefile editing/etc? The save file is not in plaintext/base64 encoded, so there was no easy way for me to edit it directly. I searched online for an Overlord save editor and a way to add the jester back, but turned up empty on both fronts.